# Leaflet Search Filter only exact matches

Tags: javascript, search, leaflet, fuse.js

I'm using Leaflet Search and Fuse.js to search multiple leaflet layers and multiple feature.properties in each one. I've finally got the code working (but it is really messy). Only issue is that because I'm using filterData it is showing ALL markers when I search anything instead of exact matches.

Any way to show exact matches only?

```
var fuseOptions = {
  shouldSort: true,
  tokenize: true,
  threshold: 0,
  location: 0,
  maxPatternLength: 32,
  minMatchCharLength: 2,
  keys: ['properties.myKey']
};

    var fuse = new Fuse(city.features.concat(village.features.concat(gateway.features.concat(trade.features.concat(danger.features.concat(connect.features.concat(forest.features.concat(mine.features.concat(office.features.concat(farm.features.concat(fish.features.concat(annex.features)))))))))), fuseOptions), {
        keys: [
            'properties.name',
            'properties.prod1',
            'properties.extraprod1',
            'properties.extraprod2',
            'properties.extraprod3',
            'properties.extraprod4',
            'properties.extraprod5',
            'properties.buff',
            //'properties.operator'
        ]
    });
    L.control.search({
           initial: false,
           layer: allLayers,
           collapsed: false,
           casesensitive: false,
           propertyName: 'name',
           container: 'findbox',
       filterData: function(text, records) {
            var jsons = fuse.search(text),
                ret = {}, key;
            
            for(var i in jsons) {
                key = jsons[i].properties.name;
                ret[ key ]= records[key];
            }

            console.log(jsons,ret);
            return ret;
        }
    })
    .on('search:locationfound', function(e) {
        e.layer.openPopup();
    })
    .addTo(map);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this work but try:

```
filterData: function(text, records) {
            var jsons = fuse.search(text),
                ret = {}, key;
            
            for(var i in jsons) {
                key = jsons[i].properties.name;
                if(key.startsWith(text)){
                    ret[ key ]= records[key];
                }
                // Try with and without this line
                else { rect[key] = null; }
            }

            console.log(jsons,ret);
            return ret;
        }
```

Comment: The search doesn't return any results at all :( Also it seems my fuseOptions just aren't making any difference at all.. It's weird though because the more I type into the search the less results show.. Feel like something just isn't working correctly. I also realised I can limit the amount of results shown using the tooltipLimit option but I don't know how to write a function that will count all the matching results.

Comment: ok the issue is with this part ```key = jsons[i].properties.name;```

it is only checking the names for matches and not all of the properties. I'm so confused :(

Comment: Can you create a live example so that I can test? Maybe over your own server or a jsfiddle

Comment: There is a live example here: https://www.blackdesertfoundry.com/map

Sorry in advance for how messy the code is D: The search code is in the index.html file

Example searches: should be able to search for strawberry and only "Viv Foretta Hamlet - Farming" should show up.

Comment: Can you add the files to jsfiddle.net? I can't open your url because my company firewall block it (no game sites allowed)

Comment: Not sure if this will work: https://jsfiddle.net/bdu5q8xo/1/

The search controls begin on line 572